# How to return a default value with `cond` in PicoLisp

Tags: lisp, picolisp

I'm trying to return a default value when the other conditionals are not met with the `cond` statement. How can I achieve this in PicoLisp?

```
(de fib (n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) 0)
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))) ) )

(prinl (fib 1)) # prints 1
(prinl (fib 5)) # prints nothing
(bye)
```

[Example coded with this reference code](https://picolisp.com/wiki/?home).

```
(let (Foo "bar")
  (cond
    ((not Foo) "No foo for you")
    ((lst? Foo) (map 'my-list-function Foo))
    ((= Foo "bar") "Foobar")
    "Nothing is true" ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`T`](https://software-lab.de/doc/refT.html#T) global to return a default value with [`cond`](https://software-lab.de/doc/refC.html#cond).

```
(de fib (n)
  (cond
    ((= n 0) 0)
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (T (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))) ) )

(prinl (fib 1)) # prints 1
(prinl (fib 5)) # prints 5
(bye)
```